# VS2012: Release vs Debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-deployment

There is an Azure Cloud service with webrole project developed in ASP.NET MVC 4 and JQuery.
When the cloud service is deployed with Debug build, everything works fine.
But Release build has UI issues and also some exceptions like:

> Error: Message: The ViewData item that has the key 'XyzID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.
>   Exception Name: System.InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'XyzID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

What could be the reasons?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this is conditional compilation sections. Look for sections marked like

`#if DEBUG`

`#if RELEASE`

In fact try to run the project locally with different build configuration such as `Debug`, `Release`, `Cloud` etc and you may be able to reproduce the issue.